# Jquery selector by width

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Would it be possible to select a table with a specific width ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes like this:

```
$('table[width="700"]')
```

Or you can get all tables having width with whatever value like this:

```
$('table[width]')
```

Comment: Will this apply to width set in CSS also?

Comment: @rahul: Nope it will look for inline width attribute and the OP did not mention it specifically but i think @Eric has done it fine. I just wrote what came into the mind while reading the question. :)

Answer (score 15):

Use the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#using-filter-function) function:

```
$('table').filter(function() {
    return $(this).width() > 700;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Or create your own selector

```
$.expr[':'].atLeast700px = function(obj){
  return $(obj).width() >= 700;
};


$('table:atLeast700px');  // returns all your tables 700px or wider
```

Comment: +1 You could also do it with a parameter: `$.expr[':'].widthGt = function(obj, stack, meta) { return $(obj).width() >= parseInt(meta[3], 10); }; $('table:widthGt(700)');`

Comment: For a fully parametrized version (greater than, less than, equals etc), take a look at this SE answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30688276/467386