# Select div with specific width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quick Question:
How to select a div with certain width. For example we have 10 div in one page, I want to select the one that has 200px width and do something.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: *If* this div is always going to be the same, you should use id's. Otherwise, maybe select all of them and loop to select the first one that has this width?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What JCOC611 said:

```
var $theDivs = $('div').filter(function() { return $(this).width() === 200; });
```

That'd get you a jQuery object with all matching (200px) divs in it. Might not be the fastest thing in the world; it'd probably be better to more directly and explicitly identify your page elements, if you can.

Comment: @Thanks Pointy, This is what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also extend jQuery's pseudo-selectors, like this:

```
// Extend jQuery ":" pseudo selector to include a width() test

$.extend( $.expr[':'], {
    width: function ( element, index, selectorMatches ) {
        var expr = selectorMatches[3].match( /^\s*([<>]?={0,1})?\s*(\d+)\s*$/ ),
            elementWidth = $( element ).width(),
            targetWidth, comparisonOperator;

        if ( ! expr ){
            console.log( "invalid expression" );
            return false;
        }

        comparisonOperator = expr[1] || "==";
        targetWidth = parseInt( expr[2] );

        return eval( elementWidth + comparisonOperator + targetWidth );
    }
});


// Valid expressions are:
// :width( 200 ), :width( = 200 ), :width( == 200 )
// :width( > 200 ), :width( >= 200 )
// :width( < 200 ), :width( <= 200 )
$('div:width( 200 )').hide();
```

This IMHO is a lot more fun than using `filter()`, but [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-custom-selector-vs-filter) shows it to be just a little bit slower (4% slower).

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0a0cbmtj/) that you can play around with.