# jQuery: How can i select all elements whichs width is more than 400?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select div with specific width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998191/select-div-with-specific-width)

Is there a way to select all elements based on dimensions? 
LIKE

```
$('*[width()>'400px']')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$("*").filter(function () {
    return $(this).width() > 400;
}).hide();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/filter/